# pgfkeys : print values in the order they were called

Tags: environments, pgfkeys

I would like to create an environment that prints the parameters in the order they were called using pgfkeys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
/info/.is family, /info,
default/.style = {
    email=\empty,
    phone=\empty,
    linkedin=\empty,
    address=\empty
},
email/.estore in = \email,
phone/.estore in = \phone,
linkedin/.estore in = \linkedin,
address/.estore in = \address
}
\newcommand{\separator}{\hspace{0.3cm}\textbullet{}\hspace{0.3cm}}
\newcounter{paramcounter}
\newenvironment{info}[1][]{%
\pgfkeys{/info, default, #1}%
\setcounter{paramcounter}{0}
\ifx\email\empty\else \stepcounter{paramcounter} \noindent Email: \email\fi%
\ifx\phone\empty\else\ifnum\value{paramcounter}>0\separator\fi \stepcounter{paramcounter} Phone: \phone\fi%
\ifx\linkedin\empty\else\ifnum\value{paramcounter}>0\separator\fi \stepcounter{paramcounter} LinkedIn: \linkedin\fi%
\ifx\address\empty\else\ifnum\value{paramcounter}>0\separator\fi \stepcounter{paramcounter} Address: \address\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\info[linkedin=john, phone=0630801266, address=Rabat, email= john@gmail.com]\\
\end{document}
```

In the above example the parameters are printed always in that order:

> Email: john@gmail.com • Phone: 0630801266 • LinkedIn: john • Address: Rabat

What I want to do is, if I call the environment that way :

```
\info[linkedin=john, phone=0630801266, address=Rabat, email= john@gmail.com]
```

it should print the values in the order I call them :

> LinkedIn: john • Phone: 0630801266 • Address: Rabat • Email: john@gmail.com

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you! Glad to be here

Comment: You are defining an environment `info` but then you are using `\info` as a macro. Do you need the values later or do you just want to typeset the informations in the given order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a key-value structure is that the order of the keys doesn't matter, so I think this will be difficult to do within `pgfkeys`. However, you can write a simple key-value parser yourself that does preserve the order using the `listofitems` package, which provides a macro `\foreachitem` to iterate over a list.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\separator}{\hspace{0.3cm}\textbullet{}\hspace{0.3cm}}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\newcounter{paramcounter}
\newcommand{\info}[1]{%
\def\args{#1}%
\setsepchar{,}%
\readlist*\argslist\args%
\setsepchar{=}%
\setcounter{paramcounter}{0}%
\foreachitem\currentarg\in\argslist{%
\readlist*\argparts\currentarg%
\ifnum\value{paramcounter}>0\separator\fi%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\argparts[1]}{linkedin}}{LinkedIn}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\argparts[1]}{phone}}{Phone}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\argparts[1]}{address}}{Address}{}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\argparts[1]}{email}}{E-mail}{}%
: \argparts[2]%
\stepcounter{paramcounter}%
}}
\begin{document}
\info{linkedin=john, phone=0630801266, address=Rabat, email= john@gmail.com}

\info{address=Main Street, phone=1234567, email=mary@gmail.com, linkedin=mary}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is to print the informations in the order they were specified you can let PGFKeys do just that.

Here, I'm using a `\begingroup … \endgroup` to keep the changes to `utils/separator` local, we could also use something similar to your `default` key.

I've added the `hyperref` package to show how it easy it is to use the arguments with its `\href` macro to create custom links. (Feel free to adjust the color settings, though.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\pgfkeys{
  /info/.is family, /info,
  utils/create info/.style 2 args={#1/.code={\pgfkeysalso{utils/separator}#2}},
  utils/separator/.style={utils/separator/.code=\hspace{0.3cm}\textbullet\hspace{0.3cm}},
  utils/create info=   {email}{Email:    \href{mailto:#1}{#1}},
  utils/create info=   {phone}{Phone:    \href{tel:#1}{#1}},
  utils/create info={linkedin}{LinkedIn: \href{https://linkedin.com/in/#1}{#1}},
  utils/create info= {address}{Address:  #1}
}
\newcommand*\info[1]{\par\noindent\begingroup\pgfkeys{/info,#1}\endgroup\par}%
\begin{document}
\info{linkedin = john, phone = 0630801266, address = Rabat, email = john@gmail.com}
\info{address = Home, email = home@example.com, phone = 0123456789, linkedin = pete}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put in to provide a clear and informative answer, thank you!